# Not Supported on Windows Azure Machine

Tags: c#, azure, msbuild

I just upgraded my project to the Azure 2.6 SDK. My roles start on the emulator and they appear to work fine. In my build log, I see this message:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.6\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets(2695,5): warning WAT250: The project '{0}' targets '{1}' which is not supported on the Microsoft Azure virtual machine (OSFamily = '{2}').  To make sure that the role starts, update the 'osFamily' attribute in the service configuration file '{3}'.  See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=262840 from more information.

Here is my CFG file:

```
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="CloudService1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="3" osVersion="*" schemaVersion="2015-04.2.6">
```

Should I do anything?

Comment: Have the same problem

Answer (score 3):

[This link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-guestos-update-matrix) has the osFamily information.  As of this writing:

- **Family 6** - Windows Server 2019 - .NET Framework: 3.5, 4.7.2
- **Family 5** - Windows Server 2016 - .NET Framework: 3.5, 4.6.2
- **Family 4** - Windows Server 2012 R2 - .NET Framework: 3.5, 4.5.1
- **Family 3** - Windows Server 2012 - .NET Framework: 3.5, 4.5
- **Family 2** - Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 - .NET Framework: 3.5 (includes 2.0 and 3.0)

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-update-azure-service) is documentation on the upgrade process.